# Reverse img scale using CSS?

Tags: css, html, image, animation, scale

I am trying to do something with CSS I do no think has been done before. I have used CSS to make an image animate larger (grow in size smoothly) in scale when the mouse hovers over the img. It is a great effect, and can be used to make nice portfolios or cool menus like an apple OS X dock. However, I saw recently a site that scaled the image back, making it smaller and then showing text and thought it was great. It uses JavaScript and a hint of JQuery, but I was wondering if this can be done in CSS alone? Below is the code for scaling the image larger:

```
a:hover, a:focus { 
    z-index:440 
}
a img {
    border:0;
    -webkit-transition:all .2s; 
    -moz-transition:all .2s;
}
ul.Port a img {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;/
    -moz-transform-origin: top; 
}
a:hover img, a:focus img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

If I change the values to negative, I get issues with the img flashing in and out of proper size, and it does nto smoothly scale smaller, but becomes eradicate. Is what I am asking to do just not possible in CSS? Or am I missing something? I have played around with this for a few hours, but cannot get it to just work.

Comment: To make something smaller, you don't set scale to negative; you set scale to a value smaller than 1. (for instance, 0.5 to make it half the size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            img {
                margin-top:50px;
                -webkit-transition:all .2s; 
                -moz-transition:all .2s;
            }
            img:hover {
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
                -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="top.png" alt="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know what I was doing wrong, I set it to 1, but it didn't change size, so I went to -1, and it went crazy, I wasn't thinking in terms of decimals, so after reading your response, I changed the 1.5 to .7 or .6 and it works great. I was think in solid numbers only. I am not sure what the hell I was thinking, but thanks for smacking my brain into place. !!!!